# Apple System Log time in milliseconds?

Tags: ios, macos, logging

NSLog() uses timestamps with millisecond resolution, but is a blunt instrument because all its log messages are at the Warning level.

Apple System Log is a much more fine-grained system, with 8 different levels. BUT... its timestamps have only 1-second resolution. I read the man page about time formats, but they all seem to be to the second only.

Clearly this information is available, at least to NSLog. A lot can go on in a second; is there a way to get better resolution with ASL?

Comment: In `Console.app` select `View` > `Milliseconds`.

Comment: That's great, never saw that. However, this doesn't affect the Xcode console log. This raises a new question: where in all the log files are Xcode's logs for iOS devices running in the simulator or on an iOS device?

Comment: I believe it's location is `~/Library/Logs/iOS Simulator/<version>/`

Comment: Strangely, that location has no logs since July -- about when I upgraded to Xcode 6 (beta). Hmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append `".#"` to the time format in ASL (and syslog) to specify the precision.  Thus `"utc.3"` would format in UTC format with milliseconds.  You can add this to both the `msg_fmt` or `time_fmt` arguments.

Time format precision appears to only be documented in [syslogd(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/syslog.1.html).  I am not sure why it didn't make it to [asl(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/asl.3.html).

For example, using `asl_add_output_file` and specifying in the `time_fmt` might look like this:

```
// setup, do once!
aslclient log = asl_open(NULL, NULL, 0);
asl_add_output_file(log, STDERR_FILENO,
    "$Time $((Level)(str)) - $Message", // $Time here uses time_fmt arg on next line 
    ASL_TIME_FMT_UTC ".3", // time_fmt: append ".3" for milliseconds here
    ASL_FILTER_MASK_UPTO(ASL_LEVEL_DEBUG), ASL_ENCODE_SAFE);

// example log
asl_log(log, NULL, ASL_LEVEL_INFO, "Hello");

// Note in the above ASL_TIME_FMT_UTC is #defined to "utc", so the we're
// using compile-time string concatenation of "utc" ".3" to "utc.3".
// Alternately you can just specify "utc.3" directly.
```

and output:

```
2016-02-01 19:16:39.561Z Info - Hello
```

Specifying in `msg_fmt` argument of `asl_add_output_file`  might look like this:

```
// setup, do once!
aslclient log = asl_open(NULL, NULL, 0);
asl_add_output_file(log, STDERR_FILENO,
    // in msg_fmt below, use ISO8601 + ".6" for microseconds
    "$((Time)(ISO8601.6)) $((Level)(str)) - $Message",
    ASL_TIME_FMT_UTC,
    ASL_FILTER_MASK_UPTO(ASL_LEVEL_DEBUG), ASL_ENCODE_SAFE);

// example log
asl_log(log, NULL, ASL_LEVEL_INFO, "Hello");
```

and output:

```
2016-02-01T14:16:39.562030-05 Info - Hello
```

(I would caution that the above snippets of code are only meant to demonstrate specifying the time format precision in ASL.  Actual usage should likely involve a `dispatch_once` for setup, use a serial dispatch queue for logging.)

Answer (score 0):

Use ts shell command to add milliseconds to any log.

```
idevicesyslog | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%.S]'
```